Error Code: 3780. Referencing column '%s' and referenced column '%s' in foreign key constraint 'travela_payment_ibfk_2' are incompatible
I have created database for hotel booking website. I have created travela_payment table to keep track of user's transactions. I have added foreign keys for user_id but unable to add for hotel_name and room_type. Below here is the exception I'm getting

Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'hotel_name' and referenced
column 'hotel_name' in foreign key constraint 'travela_payment_ibfk_2'
are incompatible.

travela_hotels
CREATE TABLE `travela_hotels` (
  `hotel_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `hotel_location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `hotel_number` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `hotel_country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `hotel_price` float NOT NULL,
  `hotel_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `availability_duration` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hotel_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hotel_number_UNIQUE` (`hotel_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hotel_location_UNIQUE` (`hotel_location`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hotel_id_UNIQUE` (`hotel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin

travela_packages
CREATE TABLE `travela_packages` (
  `package_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb3_bin,
  `packages_url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`package_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `package_id_UNIQUE` (`package_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin

travela_payment
CREATE TABLE `travela_payment` (
  `payment_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_method` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `paypal_email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hotel_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `room_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_range` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`payment_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `travela_payment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `travela_members` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin

